# Problem when making left-side navigation menu full size

Tags: html, css, sticky

I'm trying to make a base layout with a left-side menu, right-side content and a top header that scrolls with the page. The content on the right side should also scroll with the main scrollbar.

My (*for me unsolvable*) problem starts, when I want the left side to be full size (height 100%) because in some cases i want to subtract the header from this.

With this **example** (https://jsfiddle.net/5q42xvwu/) it is easier to explain. I just want to have the text "TOP SIDER" and "BOTTOM SIDER" always on the screen regardless of whether the header is on the screen or not. So the **left side should change the size** depending on whether the header is on visible.

I don't know if and how this is possible with CSS. I already know that it is easily possible with JS.

I hope someone can help me with this problem, I already wasted several hours with this. Thank you :)

Here the code (in the fiddle):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .header {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .main {
            background-color: green;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .sider {
            width: 200px;
            background-color: cornflowerblue;
            height: 100vh; /* I think here is the problem */
            position: sticky;
            top:0;
            align-self: flex-start;
        }

        .inner-sider {
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="sider">
        <div class="inner-sider">
            <div>TOP SIDER</div>
            <div>BOTTOM SIDER</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        MAIN CONTENT
<!--        SIMULATE A LAGE CONTENT PAGE-->
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        END OF MAIN CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit to further clarify:**
The two inner `<div>` are only there to represent the top and the lower part of the "Inner Sider". In the real example instead of the ".inner-sider" there should be a full hight menu.

Comment: I think its not possible with css only... but I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Added classes and sticky positioning to top and bottom siders. Hope it does not break your content layout!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sider {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  height: 100vh; /* I think here is the problem */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  align-self: flex-start; 
}



.inner-sider {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* new styles below: */
.inner-top {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.inner-bottom {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="sider">
        <div class="inner-sider">
            <div class="inner-top">TOP SIDER</div>
            <div class="inner-bottom">BOTTOM SIDER</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        MAIN CONTENT
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>END OF MAIN CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your try. I probably abstracted the problem a little bit to much and clarified to little. The two inner divs are only there to represent the top and the bottom of the .inner-sider. In the real thing, there is a full hight menu instead of the .inner-sider.
Never the less, thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Is it a problem if all the menu items are distributed along two elements, one at the top and another at the bottom, with some space in the middle filling the change of height?

Comment: Yea, this would be a problem, they all need to be in the same ul-Tag. They even are too large sometimes. Then the container (here the inner-sider) should be scrollable.

Comment: Here is a fiddle more like the real example. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/d2y6vom3/2/) There you can see, that the last element isn't visible when scrolling the menu, only if you scroll the content, the last element gets visible. This translates to the base problem: I need the sider to be always the full height (sometimes without the header) so only dependent if the header is visible or not.

Comment: I need to change the height of the side div depending on the scroll. I am starting to believe that css alone cannot do this one. Sticky positioning only changes the coordinates of the element and media queries are unable to read scroll.

Comment: Okey, than it could be that it is really not possible. (which would be sad). Because this is the correct answer, you can make an answer out of it, so i can accept it. (If you would like)

Comment: Thanks, I would! Do you know how to make it with javascript?

Comment: Yea, its not so hard with javascript. I will have to make it in the next few days.

Comment: OK, let me know if you have any problem. I made some js to change sizes in the past.